# PHPMyAdmin enter host address manually

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to run a copy of PHPMyAdmin that will allow me to enter the host address manually and connect to any Server on demand. 
So I need to get a form field to display on the login page so that I can enter the host name. 
I know it must be possible, as I have used a hosting provider that does this, and i'm sure PHPMyAdmin used to work this way before they added the ability to have the server configs, but I cannot find anything n the docs on this.

Please do not send me instructions on how to add servers in the config file, I know how to do this, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the AllowArbitraryServer directive to true in your config file like this:

```
$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;
```

See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_AllowArbitraryServer

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but nothing changed, I still do not get the server form field to type the host name/ip into.

Comment: And did you reload the login page?

Comment: Can you post your config.inc.php, obfuscating sensitive details? And which phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: If my answer above was helpful please indicate it.

Comment: @snake make sure the config file is named correctly and the path is correct

Comment: Binar web, you are replying to a question that was posted nearly 5 years ago 